# PHP function Absolute URL Display Problem

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to get my function to display my categories absolute url address for example `http://www.example.com/cat/sub-1/sub-2/sub-3/` But I keep getting `http://www.example.com/cat//sub-3/` can some one help me correct this problem. Please be detailed as possible since I'm farily new to PHP.

Here is my PHP function

```
function allCategories(){
    global $parent_url;
    global $url;
    $nodeList = array();
    $tree = array();
    $query = mysqli_query(database(),"SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id, category LIKE '%more%', category ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $nodeList[$row['id']] = array_merge($row, array('children' => array()));
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);

    foreach($nodeList as $nodeId => &$node) {
        if(!$node['parent_id'] || !array_key_exists($node['parent_id'], $nodeList)){
            $tree[] = &$node;
            $url = $parent_url . $node['url'];
            $url = str_replace('&#063;cat=', '', $url);
            echo '<li><a href="http://www.example.com/cat/' . strip_tags($url) . '" title="' . strip_tags($node['category']) . ' Link" class="category-headers">' . strip_tags($node['category']) . '</a>';   
        } else {
            $nodeList[$node['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$node;
            $url = $parent_url . $node['url'];
            $cat_num = array('&#063;cat=','&#038;sub1=','&#038;sub2=');
            $url = str_replace($cat_num, '/', $url);
            echo '<li><a href="http://www.example.com/cat/' . strip_tags($url) . '" title="' . strip_tags($node['category']) . ' Link">' . strip_tags($node['category']) . '</a>';              
        }

    echo '</li>';        
    } 

    echo '</ol>';  
    unset($node);
    unset($nodeList);
}

allCategories();
```

Comment: Word of advice: avoid `global` whenever possible, especially if `$url` doesn't need to be accessible outside of this function. You want to avoid polluting the global scope as much as possible.

Comment: @Tieson T. advice taken, but do you have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your query is erroring out at the MySQL level, and you don't have anything set up to tell you so (especially if warnings are turned off in the `php.ini` file).

Try adding something like this to the line that starts with `$query`:

`or die( "<h1>SELECT query failed!</h1> <p>Error: " . mysqli_error( $dbc ) . "</p>"  );`

`$dbc` needs to be replaced with whatever variable holds your database connection.

Obviously, this is for debugging only. You would replace `die` with some error-handling function on a production server.

Comment: Hmm. Might need to `print_r( $row )` so that you can see what you're getting back from the database.

Comment: Did you add it inside the `while` loop? (Not trying to be insulting, BTW, just have to ask to eliminate the obvious).

Comment: Hmm. And `database()` is a function you've defined that returns a MySQL connection?